# Single API, multple frontend clients

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm currently redesigning an application where we have a single API (.NET Core 3.1) and two frontend (React) applications. In our current solution we share the same endpoints for both clients, meaning that there is an overhead of data sent from the API because both clients need different information.

I'm looking for a convenient way to split the API so we end up having two different responses, depending on which client is sending the request. I see a few options but I'm quite unfamiliar with pros and cons (besides the obvious ones) of these approaches since I never planned an application for multiple clients.

1. Single endpoint, different data returned depending on a header/query param
2. Split the API into two APIs (but where should common endpoints land? creating the third API is an overhead for us)
3. Split controllers into two when necessary (perhaps using `partial` classes?) and just implement `GET api/resourceX/client1` separately from `GET api/resourceX/client2`

But maybe there already is a build-in solution for this in .NET Core that I'm not aware of? I tried looking for solutions but ended up getting nowhere near the answer - perhaps my keywords failed me.

Comment: Or option 4. Go Restful and have clients request the data they need by adding endpoints for all the necessary data. Then the client can combine multiple endpoints and retrieve all the data they want. Apply a caching policy to that data, and now your app can serve millions of requests on a single core instance. Really, don't differ the output of one controller method to accommodate your clients because that's a recipe for disaster. - I have learned this the hard way.

Comment: This sounds a little bit like option 3. For example - i create a virtual machine on azure and i save some of its parameters in the database. Both clients can request virtual machine's information but they should get different responses - are you saying that i should create three endpoints - one being the common things and two specific ones? If so, should I just create two separate endpoints with `/{clientId}` parameter or is it better to use headers or query parameters? That's the stuff I'm missing mostly because I have no experience with mutliple clients using my API.

Answer (score 0):

This question is somewhat opinion based and you did not give us much details about how different the needs of the two clients are, but I try to answer it.

I have the assumption that you do a CRUD API and you just serve data from database without much transformation or processing in your code. This is ok, but keep in mind that REST should be built around operations and not around data types and CRUD if we use the WSDL terms. This is somewhat related to anemic domain model (defined by Martin Fowler).

If the users of the two clients are the same, then I would add more endpoints to cover the different types of queries. You can use URI templates for this e.g. `/stuff?filter=xyz&view=verbose`. If you want to support arbitrary queries, then it is better to use a standard solution for URI queries e.g. odata instead of building your own query language. You can use headers too, but as far as I know standard HTTP headers are a lot less flexible than URI queries.

If you have different user groups for different clients based on the privileges e.g. staff and customers, then you can serve different data for the same endpoint based on the privileges. Be aware that if you handle both regular users and admins with a single client, then the code of the client can contain hints about what is accessible for an admin. If this is an issue, then you need to split up the code of the client into multiple files and serve the admin files only for people with admin privileges. Setting the proper cache header is important in this case too. Another possible solution to have different clients for different user groups.

Be aware that in the case of real REST your server gives the URIs or URI templates to the clients just like a webserver gives the links and forms to the browser. This is because the URIs can change in time and it is a lot easier to keep backward compatibility this way. The clients know what a link does based on the metadata you send with the link e.g. IANA link relations, RDF vocabularies, etc. So the only URI you need to hardcode into your clients should be the root URI of the API. Most of the people don't try to meet with this REST constraint, because it requires somewhat different than the usual mindset to do it.